# How to select metamask extension if there are many wallet extensions installed in the browser?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, metamask, ethers.js, browser-extension

Our tester faced an issue when calling my code because he installed both metamask and enkrypt extensions in his chrome browser. My code is dealing with metamask :

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function main(amountToSend, destWallet) {
  // Configuring the connection to an Ethereum node
  const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK;
  const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(
        network
  );
  // Creating a signing account from a private key
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

  // Creating and sending the transaction object
  const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
        to: destWallet,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountToSend, "ether")
  });

  // Waiting for the transaction to be mined
  const receipt = await tx.wait();
  // The transaction is now on chain!
}

require("dotenv").config();

let amount = process.argv[2];
let wallet = process.argv[3];

main(amount, wallet);
```

So how to select the metamask extension ?